# What approach should I take for electronics simulator or similar?

Tags: algorithm, simulation, simulator, circuit

I would like to build an app which is quite similar to electronics simulator. I mean any simulator with nodes interconnecting each other.

What are possible solutions for this? For example it is quite simple for a diagram like this:
[image: Basic circuit]

But what approach should I take to simulate this:

[image]

Note that the pictures are just for illustration purposes.

- On the first picture I would simply make connections like `A->B->C->D` and that's all
- On the second I could do `A->B->C->D` and connect each node to the others nodes as well but how to handle the flow?

Comment: Usually, a graph data structure will be used for something like this. What programming language are you planning to use?

Comment: `how to handle the flow` - You want to build a [directed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - anything. From C to Javascript. I actually care about the data structures used, not the language. Could you ellaborate on graph structures here?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend looking into modeling as somehing like "points" and "elements", where a "point" combines all locations in the diagram, that have the same voltage at all times.

Let's try this out on your images:

Image 1

- Has 4 Points:
- - Point 1 is the negative side of V1 AND the negative side of D1
- - Point 2 is the positive side of V1 AND the left side of the switch
- - Point 3 is the right side of the switch AND the left side of R1
- - Point 4 is the right side of R1 AND the positive side of D1
- Has 4 Elements:
- - Element 1 is V1, connected to Points 1 and 2
- - Element 2 is the switch connected to Points 2 and 3
- - Element 3 is R1 connected to Points 3 and 4
- - Element 4 is D1 connected to Points 4 and 1

Image 2

- Has only 2 Points
- - Point 1 are numbers 1-4
- - Point 2 are numbers 5-8
- Has 4 Elements, all connected to Points 1 and 2

Your implementation of the element classes (e.g. resistor, LED, Power supply, Switch) will then create either a drain from or a source to the points it is connected to. By starting from some invariant (e.g. Power supply fixing voltage on points 1 and 2) and a point in time you can then iterate over the elements, calculating the flows and the resulting voltages on the other points.

Comment: thank you. this gave me some insight